# Code get crashing at adding phone contacts query

Tags: iphone, crash, addressbook

I am able to add only showroom name to my contacts. But when I put the code to add phone numbers, further details....my code get crash. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Here is my code

```
- (IBAction)AddContact
 {   
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef Showroom = ABPersonCreate();

//adding contact name as showroom name
ABRecordSetValue(Showroom, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, ShowroomName.text , nil);

//adding phone number
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
 ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, p_BcardLabel.text, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);

 ABRecordSetValue(Showroom, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);
 CFRelease(multiPhone);
//adding emailaddress
 ABMutableMultiValueRef multiEmail =  ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
 ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiEmail, email_BcardLabel.text, kABWorkLabel,   NULL);
 ABRecordSetValue(Showroom, kABPersonEmailProperty, multiEmail, @"");
 CFRelease(multiEmail);

 //adding URL
 ABMutableMultiValueRef multiURL = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
 ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiURL, url_BcardLabel.text, kABHomeLabel, NULL);
 ABRecordSetValue(Showroom, kABPersonURLProperty, multiURL, @"");
 CFRelease(multiURL);
```

Shows following message

```
[Switching to thread 11779]
warning: Unable to read symbols for   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2   (8H7)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only to improve your code. I have checked once your code its fine working just add the following lines

```
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook,Showroom, nil);


    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook,nil); 

    objABPersonViewController=[[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc]init];

    objABPersonViewController.displayedPerson=Showroom;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objABPersonViewController animated:YES];


    CFRelease(Showroom);
```

And if you want to use mine check this out. It will also add an image named abc.png from your resource folder to the contact list.

```
 -(IBAction)addToAddressbook:(id)sender{ 
        NSString *fname=@"Person First Name";

        NSString *lname=@"Person Last Name";

        NSArray *arrayAdd=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"street Name",@"city Name",@"country code",@"zip",nil];

        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc.png" ofType:nil]];

        [self addContact:fname:lname:arrayAdd:image];
    }

    -(void) addContact:(NSString *)firstname:(NSString *)lastname:(NSArray *)arrayAddress:(UIImage *)currentImage
    {
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook=ABAddressBookCreate();

        ABRecordRef person=ABPersonCreate();

        //set Image
        NSData * dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(currentImage);

        ABPersonSetImageData(person, (CFDataRef)dataRef, nil);

        //set FirstName and LastName
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,firstname, nil);

        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty,lastname, nil);


        //Add Address
        ABMutableMultiValueRef address=ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);

        NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        [addressDictionary setObject:[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];

        [addressDictionary setObject:[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:1]forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];

        [addressDictionary setObject:[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:2] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey];

        [addressDictionary setObject:[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:3] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];

        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, addressDictionary, kABHomeLabel, nil);

        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, nil);

        ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook,person, nil);

        ABAddressBookSave(addressBook,nil); 

        objABPersonViewController=[[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc]init];

        objABPersonViewController.displayedPerson=person;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objABPersonViewController animated:YES];


        CFRelease(person);

    }
```

for any further query just ask... Happy to help

Comment: I am fetching contacts from web-service. aMarker are my attributes...aMarker.name,aMarker.phone,aMarker.url etc which I am taking on my button1,button2.. label and finally button with add in contact. Where I will make changes in your code to use in my app. Please suggest...

Comment: ahh Problem solved......actually I was passing "p_BcardLabel.text" wich I have only set define but not taken on UIview. Thats y code was crashing. Now working fine...

Comment: Hello coolanil: Do you know how to open add contact window in my iphone app. currently I am successfully adding contacts detail only...

Comment: Hi Anil I have one doubt again....when I am adding any contacts with address(australian showroom address) the label "India" is also get added in to contact list. For eg 12 Stretton PI WA Balcatta is the aus address. But it get added with  12 Stretton PI WA Balcatta ""India"". Do you have any idea??

Comment: I have paste question for the same with code on link      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728451/add-contact-from-iphone-application-bugg

Answer (score 0):

This is the Answer to your question Navnath. Apple provides ABNewPersonViewController to open the particular add contact view.Add the ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate in your header file.

case 1:Application is view based:-

```
     -(IBAction)displayContactAddWindow:(id)sender{
    ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
    picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];

    [picker release];
    [navigation release];
}
```

case 2:Application is navigation based:-

-(IBAction)displayContactAddWindow:(id)sender{

```
    ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];

    picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];

   }

- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Actually It should load the edit window with contact I have just add on click event. So user can edit or delete entire contact....I did it smthing like above u said but it gives warning warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit (file not found).
warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit

Comment: Also there is no default delete method on edit contact window?? If user dont want saved contact then he can delete that...