# Add contact from iPhone application bugg

Tags: iphone

I am successfully adding contact address in iPhone  through my application by using below code

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef Showroom = ABPersonCreate();
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [addressDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Address_Bcard.text] forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, addressDictionary, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(Showroom, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress,@"");
    CFRelease(multiAddress);

    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, Showroom, nil);
    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil)
CFRelease(Showroom);
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

I am adding australian address from application to iPhone contacts eg. Sydney Australia. Instead of **Sydney Australia** the iPhone contact shows **Sydney Australia India** in addess field. How to remove this bugg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify the country in the address field of the contact it will automatically takes the country you live.

A way to specify the country code to set another country is:-
Change to

```
Settings -> General -> International -> Region Format to "Australia".
```

But the problem is this will change all the other contacts also.

There is also a discussion on apple site. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2659179?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Ok so if user reside at Autralia or other coutry the label India will not come......it will be according to user country right???

Comment: yah if he doesn't set his Region format in iphone or set inside the application.

Comment: After setting Settings -> General -> International -> Region Format to "Australia". The contact you add will have Australia as country